# Using Python Blob Trigger as Durable Client in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I want to use Python Blob Trigger as a durable function client to trigger an orchestrated process, but I don't see any option for blob trigger in durable function can any one guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the **`__init__.py`** and **`function.json`** files of **BlobTrigger** as follows:

**`__init__.py`:**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

async def main(myblob: func.InputStream, starter: str):
    logging.info("Python blob trigger function processed blob)  

    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new('YourNewDurableFunction')
```

**`function.json`:**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "ContainerName/{name}",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "durableClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python Blob Trigger as a durable function client to trigger an orchestrated process, you need **two** functions:

- One for **durable function** (orchestrator) itself
- Another for the **Blob trigger**.

Make use of below script to create **`blob trigger function`**:

```py
[FunctionName("StartOrchestratorBlobTrigger")]
    public async Task StartOrchestratorBlobTrigger(
     [BlobTrigger("sample-workitems/{name}", Connection = "CloudSightStorage")] 
      Stream myBlob,string name,
   [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient durableOrchestrationClient,ILogger log)
{
    // get your blob content, and desrialize if you need and pass it orchestrator instead of stream as below
    await durableOrchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("YourNewDurableFunction", myBlob);
}
```

In the above function, The **`OrchestrationTrigger`** would be used as a trigger for your durable function.

To create **durable function**, make use of below sample script:

```py
[FunctionName("YourNewDurableFunction")]
public async Task YourNewDurableFunction
(
[OrchestrationTrigger]
DurableOrchestrationContextBase orchestrationContext,ILogger logger)
{
// Call activity functions here.
}
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Use durable function with blobstorage trigger and i get an error - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/59760/use-durable-function-with-blobstorage-trigger-and.html) aakash-sharma answered

[Durable Function Blob Trigger - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784657/durable-function-blob-trigger) by Sebastian Achatz

[Bindings for Durable Functions - Azure | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp%2C2x-durable-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but do you have a python script please? it would be perfect.

Comment: Please refer this link for [python script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=python#start-instances)